# Building column assignment from list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign values to a column (lets call it 'AAA') based on other columns ('BBB', 'CCC') in a pandas dataframe. It works great when I know the exact column names, but in my scenario, 'BBB' and 'CCC' come from a list.

A loop works, but is there a more elegant and faster solution?

```
columns = ['BBB', 'CCC']
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [4, 5, 6, 7], 
    'BBB': [10, 20, 30, 40], 
    'CCC': [100, 50, -30, -50]})

#This obviously works
df.loc[(df['BBB'] > 40) | (df['CCC'] > 40), 'AAA'] = 0.1

#This works as well
for col in columns:
    df.loc[df[col]>40, 'AAA'] = 0.1
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `>40` and `>=40`, or should they both be the same?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo up there. It is >40 for both - corrected

Comment: @anky_91 thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, You need [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over `axis=1` here:

```
df.AAA=np.where(df[columns].gt(40).any(1),0.1,df.AAA)
#df.AAA=df.AAA.mask(df[columns].gt(40).any(1),0.1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0  0.1   10  100
1  0.1   20   50
2  6.0   30  -30
3  7.0   40  -50
```